# Migrating to WSO2 IS? How can existing passwords hash be migrated into Jdbc Store like MySql

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can someone provide me what is best way to move passwords(hashed using Bcrypt) stored in DB to WSO2 jdbc store?
What i understand from WSO2 documentation it doesnt support Bcrypt, how do i move to WSO2 IS without my users go through change password flow.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write a custom user store manager as described in [Writing a Custom User Store Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager). Then you can configure WSO2 IS to use this custom user store manager as given in the document. This way you don't need to change the passwords of existing users.